# Find the distribution and density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}$ iid, with density $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\theta}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}$, find the distribution function and density of $\max{X_{i}}$.

My approach: Let $T=\max\{X_{i};1\leq i\leq n\}$, then $$F_{T}(t)=P(T\leq t)=P(\max\{X_{i}\}\leq t)=1-P(\max\{X_{i}\}>t)$$
$$=1-P(X_{1}>t)\cdots P(X_{n}>t)=1-[P(X_{i}>t]^{n}=1-\left(\int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\theta}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}d\theta\right)^{n}$$
If $t\notin[-\theta,\theta]$, then $F_{T}(t)=0$. If $t\in[-\theta,\theta]$

$$F_{T}(t)=1-\left(\int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\theta}d\theta\right)^{n}$$

Comment: No, you want to keep $\max\{X_i\}\leq t$. If all each $X_i$ is less than or equal to $t$, then $t$ is the at most the max. If all of them are greater than $t$, that just means $t$ is at least the minimum.

Comment: Also be careful that the CDF $F$ is not the same as the pdf; the CDF equals to one when the value exceed the maximum of the support while the pdf equals to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As you said, $F_T(t)=P(\max\{X_i\}\le t)$. But $\max\{X_i\}\le t$ iff $X_i\le t$ for all $i$. Then $F_T(t)=P(X_1\le t)P(X_2\le t)...P(X_n\le t)=P(X_1\le t)^n=F_X(t)^n$, where $X$ could be $X_1$ or $X_2$,or ... or $X_n$.

Then, differentiating, $f_T(t)=nF_X(t)^{n-1}f_X(t)$

Now, since $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}1_{[-\theta, \theta]}(x)$, then $F_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t\frac{1}{2\theta}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2\theta}\times\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}0&\mbox{if}&t<-\theta\\\theta+t&\mbox{if}&-\theta\le t\le\theta\\2\theta&\mbox{if}&\theta<t\end{array}\right.=\dfrac{\theta+t}{2\theta}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(t)+1_{(\theta,\infty)}(t)$.

Thus

$$F_T(t)=F_X(t)^n=\left(\dfrac{\theta+t}{2\theta}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(t)+1_{(\theta,\infty)}(t)\right)^n=\left(\dfrac{\theta+t}{2\theta}\right)^n1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(t)+1_{(\theta,\infty)}(t)$$ and

$f_T(t)=nF_X(t)^{n-1}f_X(t)=n\left[\left(\dfrac{\theta+t}{2\theta}\right)^{n-1}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(t)+1_{(\theta,\infty)}(t)\right]\times\dfrac{1}{2\theta}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(t)=\dfrac{n}{2\theta}\left(\dfrac{\theta+t}{2\theta}\right)^{n-1}1_{[-\theta,\theta]}(t)$